# Prepend text to Section but only include section number in ref

Tags: sectioning, numbering, ref, renewcommand

I prepended a text to subsection but I would like to only have the corresponding number if I use `\ref{...}`

Text is prepended with:

```latex
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{Herleitung \arabic{subsection}}

\subsection{ABC}\label{a}
```

Here only '1' should be shown instead of 'Herleitung 1'.
Can I achieve this? And how?

Comment: I would suggest customizing the appearance of the `\subsection` using `titlesec` or other packages, and leave `\thesubsection` alone.

Comment: In particular, if you `\usepackage{titlesec}` and issue  `\subsectionlabel{Herleitung \thesubsection. \quad}` you should get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can change independently the formatting of the sectional title number; just modify the default `\@seccntformat` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname format#1\endcsname
    \csname format#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad % default
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\formatsubsection}{Herleitung \arabic{subsection}\quad}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\section{Titel}

\subsection{Titel}\label{test}

\ref{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can define similarly `\formatsection` to your liking. If the `\format<level>` command is undefined, the default (number followed by `\quad`) is used.